# Multiple actions registered on one broadcast Receiver is not working in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, reboot

I registered multiple intent under one receiver

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<receiver
        android:name="com.test.callerpopup.CallerPopUp"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">

 <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" ></action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" ></action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" ></action>
        </intent-filter>
```

In my Broadcast receiver class

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    String phone_state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);


    if (phone_state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING) ){
 Toast.makeText(context, "Incoming Call", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Normal execution of app is working fine but when i am restarting phone, the toast is not working . Why ? I have registered the receiver on "REBOOT" and "BOOT_COMPLETED"

Comment: try to write seperate intent-filter for every action

Comment: <intent-filter >
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" ></action>
</intent-filter >

<intent-filter >
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" ></action>
</intent-filter >

Comment: `BOOT_COMPLETED` can't be registered through the manifest, you have to register is manually in code.

Comment: in coolpad the toast is coming in little delay but in redmi not

Comment: These two <intent -filter> is not working for one receiver